# When an internet connection is present and I click on "check update" in Android Studio, I get "Connection Failed"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a valid Internet Connection. I have freshly installed Android Studio from `dev.android.com`

**Problem:**
When I click check for updates, I get a "Connection failed：Please check your network connection and try again"

Comment: Update Android studio is a pain.

Comment: Android Studio is biggest pain in my life

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Set "No Proxy"

Seems to be a bug.

I went to Preferences -> HTTP Proxy
Set the option to "No Proxy" from "Auto-detect proxy settings"

Comment: In my case,proxy was not set and I still had the issue.

Comment: where is "Preferences"? I don't find it anywhere in 2.0

Comment: @ShirishHerwade not sure about 2.0

Comment: In my case, set it to "Auto-detect proxy settings" from "No Proxy" works for me.

Answer (score 4):

add "**-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.updates.url=http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml
-Didea.patches.url=http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/**" to studio.vmoptions. Then, I can update Android Studio to version 0.2.10

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to download the patch from [here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)

[image]

The same as using the `Help > Check for Update` option.

Comment: It's NOT "The same as using the `Help > Check for Update` option." because this option only downloads a patch file of about ~10 mb as compared to re-downloading the whole IDE as mentioned in your answer.

Comment: When I say "the same" as using the help option,I mean you end up with the same update.Besides,if you don't have the internet connection problem, using the help > search for update option also redirects you to that same page.

Answer (score 0):

**start the android studio as administrator.** that helps me in android studio whenever updates/installations are failed.

Answer (score 0):

same problem, fixed re-installing Android Studio for all users!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Android Studio 2.3.2 on Mac.

After rebooting the computer it started working.

(First I tried using Automatic proxy with no success and later turn it off again.)